# How can I get the (FTest) solve_power methods in statsmodel to compute power for linear regression models?

Tags: python, statsmodels

I have recently started using the Python library statsmodel (transitioning from R). I wish to use a simple linear regression model and estimate its statistical power similar to the function `pwr.f2.test` in R (using Cohen's f2 as the effect size).

I am able to obtain the power without using any of the inbuilt functions like solve_power (in `statsmodel.stats.power`) as shown in the code below. However, while using the `statsmodels.stats.power.FTestPower()` (with the `solve_power`) I get very different results as compared to a simulated approach or the functions in R.

I was wondering if there is something I am missing while using the functions?

```py
def multipleRegressionPowerAnalysis (weight, N, num_variables, alpha=0.05, sims=2):
  signif = np.zeros(sims)
  for s in range(sims):
    x, y = sim(weight, N, num_variables)
    results = sm.OLS(y,x).fit()
    signif[s] = (results.f_pvalue<=alpha)
  empirical_power = np.mean(signif)
  R2 = sum(weight**2)
  solver = statsmodels.stats.power.FTestPower()
  f2_power = solver.solve_power(effect_size=(R2/(1-R2)), df_num=num_variables, 
    df_denom=(N-num_variables), nobs=N, alpha=alpha, 
    power=None, ncc=1) # Similar to the pwr.f2.test function in R
  f2_power = solver.solve_power(effect_size=np.sqrt(R2/(1-R2)), df_num=(N-num_variables), df_denom=(num_variables), nobs=N, alpha=alpha, power=None, ncc=1) # Updated function
  return empirical_power, f2_power

empirical_power, f2_power = multipleRegressionPowerAnalysis(np.array([0.12, 0.4, 0.05, 0.02, 0.1]), 
20, 5, sims=1000)
print(empirical_power, f2_power)

empirical_power, f2_power = multipleRegressionPowerAnalysis(np.array([0.15]), 343, 1, sims=1000)
print(empirical_power, f2_power)
```

Example 1:

- Empirical Power: 0.321
- FTestPower Function: 0.05776419010044176
- pwr.f2.test (from R): 0.2535
- Updated FTestPower Function: 0.2535272287866944

Example 2:

- Empirical Power: 0.825
- FTestPower Function: 0.05001334984233974
- pwr.f2.test (from R): 0.806
- Updated FTestPower Function: 0.8012392781285327

**Note:** The updated call is presented above and described in the comment below.

Comment: Add the call `pwr.f2.test`with numbers and results to the question for comparison. statsmodel FTestPower has a unit test compared to `pwr.f2.test`, but I don't remember details.

Comment: check with sqrt of effect size. statsmodels seems to be using Cohen's `f` and not `f_squared` as effect size definition

Comment: I was able to get the exact results by using the sqrt of Cohen's f, but I did have to interchange the degrees of freedom of the numerator and the denominator. I am not entirely sure if that is correct (but it does seem to _work_ empirically). I was wondering if the disrepancy in the empirical and in-built functions is to be expected?

Comment: The difference between empirical power from the simulations and the theoretical F-Power is small enough that it can be noise from small sample size and relatively small number of simulations. However, there could also be a small difference in how you compute simulations and effect sizes. For example, I looked at similar cases that had a small sample bias without adding an appropriate corrections.